# Scala 2.10 and Continuations (akka-dataflow) in the sbt console

Tags: scala, sbt, read-eval-print-loop, continuations, scala-2.10

What is the status of the continuations plugin in Scala 2.10; I'm slightly confused. The following setup is in the [Akka 2.2-SNAPSHOT documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dataflow.html):

```
autoCompilerPlugins := true,
libraryDependencies <+= scalaVersion {
  v => compilerPlugin("org.scala-lang.plugins" % "continuations" % "2.10.0")
},
scalacOptions += "-P:continuations:enable",
```

First, the `scalacOption` doesn't work with 2.10 anymore, and the `scalaVersion` is not actually used in the library dependencies. If I naively go ahead with 2.10 and no special configurations (remove all of the above), and Akka 2.1.0:

```
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import akka.dataflow._

flow { "Hello world!" } onComplete println
```

I get an error indicating that the continuations plug-in is *not* enabled.

---

What what is the correct approach to enable continuations in Scala 2.10?

**In particular**: How can I drop into the `sbt console` and try out the above example with `flow`. It seems I also need to make sure the compiler plugin is enabled for the REPL?

---

**EDIT**: The `scalacOptions` entry *does work*, it seems I had a typo.

Comment: Basically I'm in the same situation as [this mailing list poster](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/simple-build-tool/Uj-7zl9n3f4/oC8Nl5UdFIIJ), only with Scala 2.10 and sbt 0.12.1; according to Mark Harrah at the time, it "should work without further configuration"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this `build.sbt`:

```
autoCompilerPlugins := true

scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

libraryDependencies +=
  compilerPlugin("org.scala-lang.plugins" % "continuations" % "2.10.0")

scalacOptions += "-P:continuations:enable"
```

the following continuations-only (no Akka) example works in the REPL:

```
scala> import scala.util.continuations._

scala> reset { val i = shift { body: (Int => Unit) => body(5);
     | println("done") }; println(i) }
```

Comment: Wooop. Too stupid, I think I had a typo in the `"-P:continuations:enable"`, giving me the `"bad option"` message. Now retrying, and indeed it works (also with Akka-dataflow).